# JavaFX freezes GUI when doing a scheduled long calculation

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I am making a desktop application that will sync computer's file with the database. It is scheduled every 5 seconds to check whether there is an internet connection
I am using TimeLine for schedule and Service (Task) for repeating this task:

My schedule:

```
public void sync() {
    SyncTask syncTask = new SyncTask(bar);
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(5), 
        e -> {
            if (needSync() && syncTask.isDone()) {
                syncTask.bind();
                syncTask.start(); 
            }
    }));
    timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.play();
}
```

My SyncTask class:

```
private class SyncTask {
    private ProgressBar bar;
    public SyncTask(ProgressBar bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
    Service<Boolean> service = new Service<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        protected Task<Boolean> createTask() {
            return new Task<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call() {
                    return syncSomethingHere();
                }
            };
        }
    };

    public void bind() {
        bar.progressProperty().bind(service.progressProperty());
        bar.setVisible(true);
        service.setOnSucceeded(ev -> {
            bar.setVisible(false);
        });
    }

    public void start() {
        service.restart();
    }

    public boolean isDone() {
        return !service.isRunning();
    }

}
```

But it starts freezing my GUI whenever it needs to update. 
Is there any way that I can avoid it ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: A task in a Timeline.

Comment: So I should create a task every 5 seconds? But I am not sure why using service in that way freezes my GUI ?

Comment: You cant just run that code that handles the check in the Timeline?

Comment: Thanks! I just switched to ScheduledService and it works without freezing GUI. I think TimeLine is only suitable for doing small stuff